# Formatting array with Eclipse (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, eclipse, formatting

How to formatting arrays that all keys in a column, and all values in a column - like:

```
$a = array("test"         => "test",
           "another test" => "test2);
```

Comment: Welcome SO. Please give more information on what you want and what you have tried so that other can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambigous, but if:
1. You want to seperate pair/values into 2 arrays:

```
Foreach ($a as $b=>$c) {
    array_push($i1 , $b); array_push($i2 , $c);

}
print_r($i1); print_r($i2);
```

2. If you want only show the array you can use built-in function print_r($array);